# Different entities having an optional foreign key to the same table

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have two tables that have a foreign key to another table, but both could be optional. I'm trying to do it through attributes.

Here are the two entities

```
public class Subscription : BaseModel
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidUntil { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Regarding")]
    public virtual ICollection<RoleAssociation> Roles { get; set; } = new List<RoleAssociation>();
}


public class User : BaseModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Regarding")]
    public virtual ICollection<RoleAssociation> Roles { get; set; } = new List<RoleAssociation>();
}
```

And the table for `RoleAssociation`

```
public class RoleAssociation : BaseModel
{
    public Guid Regarding { get; set; }
           
    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Functionality Functionality { get; set; }
    public Guid FunctionalityId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }

}
```

This works and creates the correct database schema, but when I'm trying to add a `RoleAssociation` and providing a `Guid` from a `User` for example, I'm being returned the following

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_RoleAssociation_Subscription_Regarding". The conflict occurred in database 
"SecurityGateway", table "dbo.Subscription", column 'Id'.
```

It expects that I ALSO add a `RoleAssociation` for a `Subscription` which is not what I want.

I have thought of making `Regarding` optional, but I don't want any rows in that table to not have a value for this column, this would make no sense.

Any ideas ?

Comment: EF or EFCore? Please remove one of your tags. Add version tags

Comment: Currenly `Regarding` has two FK's, so the value must exist in both referenced tables.  You need to rethink the model, probably by giving each table its own seperate linking table, eg `UserRoleAssociation` and `SubscriptionRoleAssociation`.